# Is it possible to Create POLLs from Code level from the app rather than creating in Azure ME Portal?

Tags: windows-8.1, azure-mobile-engagement

Am developing a WP8.1 app using C# and XAML. I have implemented Azure ME earlier in my app.

Now am sending Announcements and Polls from Azure ME Portal.

Is it possible to send Polls from code level in the app and send the data to Azure ME?

If it is possible can anyone please help me on this how to send the Polls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question is answered on the MSDN forum here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f45f16f4-ac48-4827-b3ce-4e6cd0a3b248/is-it-possible-to-create-polls-from-code-level-from-the-app-rather-than-creating-in-azure-me-portal?forum=azuremobileengagement 
In short - you can use our APIs to do this but you need to make sure that you are not doing this from the client app side for security reasons. BTW we do monitor the MSDN forums feel free to just post question there :-)